# How to get indexof a Bitmap image?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am having a hard time to get an index of a bitmap image. I am not sure how should i suppose to do it.

What i am trying to do is:

1.)Loop a URLRequest and load bitmap pictures.

2.)Put them in individual _contentHolder

3.)Put everything in a viewport

4.)Check the index of the image when its clicked

Thanks for your time

Code

```
public var _contentHolder:Sprite = new Sprite;
public var _contentHolder1:Sprite;
public var loadedArray:Array = new Array;
public var blackBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
private var somedata:Array;
protected var Holder:Listing9 = new Listing9;
public var viewport:Viewport = new Viewport();
public var scroller:TouchScroller = new TouchScroller();

var my_url:Array = somedata;

function loadImage():void
{
    somedata = SearchVectorTest.lists;

    for (var i:int = 5; i < somedata.length; i++)
    {
        if (somedata[i])
        {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.rentaid.info/rent/" + somedata[i]));
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
        }
    }
}

function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    loadedArray.push(e.currentTarget.loader.content as Bitmap);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray.length; i++)
    {
        var currentY1:int = 200;
        e.currentTarget.loader.content.height = 200;
        e.currentTarget.loader.content.y += currentY1;
        currentY1 += e.currentTarget.loader.content.height + 300;
        _contentHolder.mouseChildren = false; // ignore children mouseEvents
        _contentHolder.mouseEnabled = true; // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
        _contentHolder.useHandCursor = true; // add hand cursor on mouse over
        _contentHolder.buttonMode = true;

        _contentHolder.addChild(loadedArray[i]);

    }

    var viewport:Viewport = new Viewport();

    viewport.y = 0;

    viewport.addChild(_contentHolder);

    var scroller:TouchScroller = new TouchScroller();
    scroller.width = 300;
    scroller.height = 265;
    scroller.x = 10;
    scroller.y = 100;
    scroller.viewport = viewport;
    addChild(scroller);

    _contentHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);
}

loadImage();

public function gotoscene(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    BitmapArray.push(loadedArray);
    var index:Number;

    index = BitmapArray.indexOf(e.target);
    trace(index);
    trace(_contentHolder);
    trace(_contentHolder.parent);

    blackBox.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
    blackBox.graphics.drawRect(-1, -1, stage.width, stage.height);
    blackBox.alpha = 0.7;
    addChild(blackBox);
    Holder.height = 300;
    Holder.width = stage.width;
    Holder.x = 0;
    Holder.y = 100;
    trace(blackBox);
    trace(blackBox.parent);
    addChild(Holder);

}

function gotoscene1(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeChild(Holder);
    removeChild(blackBox);

}
```

Comment: Quick tip : In your code, *onImageLoaded()* is called each time one image is loaded. Meaning : You're creating a Viewport each time an image has finished loading. Inversely, you're creating only one _contentHolder, and put all your images in it.

Comment: But shouldnt the images still trace an index of 0? Instead of -1? I am not sure on how i should change the code to fit each image into 1 _contentHolder than putting all the _contentHolders into 1 viewport

Comment: And i already put   for(var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray.length; i++){ _contentHolder.addChild(loadedArray[i]);}  Shouldnt it add each image into its own _contentHolder?

Comment: Concerning the trace of -1, That's because you push loadedArray itself in BitmapArray, rather than the content of loadedArray. Thus, you have an array in another array, and when you ask the index of a Bitmap, it will not find the Bitmap, since it is not in the array, but in an array in the array.

Comment: Concerning _contentHolder : Where do you create the _contentHolder ? Out of the loop. Thus, there is only one _contentHolder, and each addChild is made in the same _contentHolder.

Comment: Ahhhhh ok, i will give it a go and see if i can fix it. Thanks so much for the help!! I will get back to it later today to see if i can resolve this problem, as i have been stuck on this for a few days!

Comment: Hi i just tried directly getting the indexof of the array index = loadedArray.indexOf(e.target); but it is still -1 tho

Comment: Also regarding the _contentHolder, i tried using local var var _contentHolder: Sprite= new Sprite; But if i do that, when the second image is loaded, the first one is removed, would i have to set _contentHolder as Array? Not very sure how